# jQuery- changing class of next matching element

Tags: jquery

Here's what I have:

```
<li class="alternate"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-question"></i> Some text</li>
<li class="alternate"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-question"></i> Some other text</li>
```

I am trying to make it so that when the list element is clicked, it's icon changes class from `fa-question` to `fa-spinner fa-spin`:

```
$('li.alternate').click(function() {
    $(this).next(".fa").attr('fa-question', 'fa-spinner fa-spin');
});
```

This is not working. I can trigger an alert or something else, so the click function is being ran, it's just a problem of how I'm selecting the icon.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont want `next`, the `i` is a child of your `li`, use `find` - also target the `class`, not the attribute:

```
$(this).find(".fa").toggleClass('fa-question fa-spinner fa-spin');
```

Comment: Hmm... this looks nice, but the icon is disappearing when clicked. Some class is not being added back on correctly it seems...

Comment: Works as long as there is only one class being added. toggleClass doesn't work when adding more than 1 class???

Comment: My bad, all the classes should be contained in the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('li.alternate').click(function() {
  $(this).find(".fa").removeClass('fa-question');
  $(this).find(".fa").addClass('fa-spinner fa-spin');
});
```

#### PS: Changed next() to find() as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$('li.alternate').click(function() {
  $('.fa', $(this)).removeClass('fa-question').addClass('fa-spinner fa-spin');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(this).closest(".fa").attr('fa-question', 'fa-spinner fa-spin');
```